# C++ Qt Linker Error Cannot open file 'Files.obj'

Tags: qt, linker-errors

Sorry for bad english first of all.
Today, I downloaded and installed Qt 5, before I used Qt 4.8.4.
And my projects (old and new) dont wanna be linked.

```
D:\Qt\5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\\Webs.exe.embed.manifest">debug\Webs.exe_manifest.rc
    if not exist debug\Webs.exe if exist debug\Webs.exe.embed.manifest del debug\Webs.exe.embed.manifest
    if exist debug\Webs.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\Webs.exe.embed.manifest debug\Webs.exe_manifest.bak
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\Webs.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\Webs.exe @C:\Users\UD\AppData\Local\Temp\Webs.exe.5528.16.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Files.obj'
jom: D:\Projects\Webs\Makefile.Debug [debug\Webs.exe] Error 1104
jom: D:\Projects\Webs\Makefile [debug] Error 2
```

What can I do?

Comment: have you tried to delete your build directories and rebuild project from scratch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similiar error when I tried to link with an external library on Qt.
The library was in the Program Files (x86) folder.
To solve the problem I just replace the occurrence of 'Program Files (x86)' in the .pro file to 'PROGRA~2'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your file is missing from the project or its location is not specified properly in the .pro file of your project. Seems mostly like a resource file is missing. Can tell you more if you upload your project snapshot and .pro file.

Comment: I think problem not in that. New empty projects dosn't work with this error to.